# jQuery setTimeOut function not working

Tags: php, jquery, settimeout, slidedown

So the page starts with

```
<div id="show-quick-cart-zone"></div>
```

At the top of the page I use the load command script:

```
$('#show-quick-cart-zone').load('/loadbalance/quickcart');
```

This then inserts a cart div box onto the page like so:

```
<div id="quickcart" class="quickcart" style="display:none">
    <div class="quickcarttitle"><span>SHOPPING BAG</span></div>
    <strong>Total</strong> £<?=$CartTotal?><br />
    <a href="/cart?ref=quick-cart"><img src="secure-checkout.png"></a>
    <a onclick="jQuery('#quickcart').slideUp(500);" href="#close-quick-cart"><img src="continue-shopping.png" style="margin-top:8px"></a>
</div>
```

I use a normal hyper link to slideToggle it to appear on and off.

I want it so that if the user has the ?x=1 query in their URL, it preloads the box by sliding it down once loaded via load:

I have the following jQuery function. It basically should slideDown a cart div once the page has loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<? if($_GET["x"]=="1"){ ?>
function showCart() {
    $('#quickcart').slideDown(500);
    Cufon.replace('.quickcart');
}
// Toggle the Quick Cart (uses Load Balance for higher TPS no que!)
// showCart();
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Code to do stuff immediately
    setTimeout(showCart, 0);
});
<? } ?>
</script>
```

The box however does not slideDown with no errors. I want it so that if the user is on a normal page like so:

```
/cart/product.php
```

nothing happens.

However if they're on `/cart/product.php?x=1`

The box will slideDown as default indicating a new item added.

Comment: "The box however does not slideDown with no errors."  That is an extremely confusing statement.  What is your problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding some time to the timeout?

Comment: Why not just call it inside of `document.ready`?

Comment: Are you sure `<? if($_GET["x"]=="1"){ ?>` evaluates to true? can you place an alert and confirm that the code inside this if statement actually runs?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/xWKmK/  the code seems fine.  Perhaps its loading too quickly?  I'm just giving suggestions.

Comment: Stop using `<?` please and use `<?php`.

Comment: "The box however does not slideDown with no errors." Does this mean you are getting errors? If so what errors?

Comment: I just tried your site... it works fine.  What browser are you working off of?

Comment: Yeah I just tried your site in every major browser on windows.  No issues.  Perhaps this is a cached on your end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.load` function takes some time to complete, probably longer time than the document takes to have the correct state. So try something like:

```
$('#show-quick-cart-zone').load('/loadbalance/quickcart', function() {
    // this will execute when the ajax load is complete
    showCart();
});
```

Comment: Look at the demo. The load function loads rapid!

Comment: "rapid" is not a technical term, I would make sure that the element is present before attempting to slide it.

Comment: Glad I could help. You better get your head around asynchronous loading and working with callbacks in JavaScript, it is one of the most common areas of confusion for a linear programmer.

Comment: Can you explain or send a tutorial. I thought that because I have already loaded that chunk of HTML, it should fit inside the empty HTML which it does; I then thought I could call elements from it but did not know it had to also be called within the same .load()